# staging subdomain works but test subdomain mirrors parent domain on nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain, ubuntu-14.04

I created a **staging** subdomain for say, example.com and it works fine. Later, I created *test.example.com* and it doesn't serve files from it's configured directory. It just mirrors the parent domain.

In the DNS manager, I created **test** subdomain just like **staging**, then I created a config file for nginx again the same as staging, removed a previous host file entry that pointed test.example.com to 127.0.0.1, restarted the servers but in vain.

Point worthy of mention here is that I am using a SSL certificate for the parent domain. So the server name for parent domain is like this:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com
 ...
}
...
...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and for the test subdomain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com
...
}
```

Could anyone kindly point me in the direction of a solution? I maybe missing something very basic.

Comment: Why are some people so quick to downvote I don't understand? This platform is for asking questions I believe. Do I have to show you my browser history to make you believe I did a lot of research for two days before posting a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a really stupid mistake but it can certainly happen with anyone. Turns out it was only a matter of correctly creating symlinks for nginx vhosts. So for example if I had a configuration file named test, to create a symlink I was doing something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test
```

instead of this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is behaving as though the new configuration has not come into effect.

Some `nginx` configurations use a symlink to a `sites-enabled` directory.

You need to restart `nginx` whenever its configuration is changed.

Use `nginx -t` to test the configuration file for syntax errors. If a running `nginx` fails to restart, it just continues to use the old configuration.

Use `nginx -T` to display the complete configuration across all include files, to ensure that the new configuration fragment is being read.

Clear the browser cache between each change to the `nginx` configuration to avoid erroneous test results.

Comment: I understand the symlink stuff, thank you, and I tested the configuration too. All looks fine. Yet the problem persists.

Comment: Tried that but didn't see any error.

Comment: Your answer was in the right direction but I could solve my problem only today when doing something similar.